# Swift UI navigation from splash screen to another screen automatically with delay time

Tags: ios, navigation, delay, swiftui

i am new in IOS and Swift UI, i cant navigate to login screen after splash screen. HOW CAN I NAVIGATE TO LOGIN SCREEN? please help me out!! i really appreciate all your answers.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Dispatch

struct SplashScreen: View {
    let login = LoginScreen()
    let color = Color.init("black_1")
//    let color = Color.white
    var body: some View {
        let stack = VStack(alignment: .center){
            Image("logo")
            }.background(color).onAppear(perform: {
            gotoLoginScreen(time: 2.5)
        })

        return stack
    }
}

func gotoLoginScreen(time: Double){
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(time)) {
        print("gotoLoginScreen")
    }
    return
}

struct SplashScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SplashScreen()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that you probably won't want to go back to the splash screen after you are already on the `LoginScreen` I would suggest another approach and in particular to change the `rootView` of the `UIHostingController` in `SceneDelegate`.

If you want to push to the next screen you can use the following refactor of your code:

```
struct SplashScreen: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    let login = LoginScreen()
    let color = Color.init("black_1")

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image("logo")
                NavigationLink(destination: login,
                               isActive: $isActive,
                               label: { EmptyView() })
            }
            .background(color)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                self.gotoLoginScreen(time: 2.5)
            })
        }
    }

    func gotoLoginScreen(time: Double) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(time)) {
            self.isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your approach is a right one, i also do like this by using an boolean var isActive to show and hide the Splash Screen after from Login Screen

Comment: my code in Login Screen: //splash screen
          VStack(alignment: .center){
            SplashScreen()
            .opacity(showSplash ? 1 : 0)
            .onAppear {
                self.showSplashScreen(time: 2.5)
              }
          }

and in SceneDelegate: i start the Login Screen first instead of Splash Screen.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isActive:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            if self.isActive {
            
            LoginScreen()
            
            } else {
                
                Image("logo")
                
            }
            
        }.onAppear {
          
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.5) {
           
                withAnimation {
                    self.isActive = true
                }
            }
        
    }
    
    }
    
}


struct LoginScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text("Welcome to")
            Text("the LoginView")
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

import SwiftUI

```
struct LoginScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Welcome to")
            Text("the LoginView")
        }.navigationBarTitle("Login")
    }
}

struct SplashScreen: View {
    @State private var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image("logo")
                NavigationLink(destination: LoginScreen(),
                               isActive: $isActive,
                               label: { EmptyView() })
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                self.gotoLoginScreen(time: 2.5)
            })
        }
    }

    func gotoLoginScreen(time: Double) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(time)) {
            self.isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but it is not the correct answer.

Comment: @Phu: Originally I didn't understand your question, but I do see what you're trying to achieve now. I've update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score -2):

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: LoginView()) {
                Text("Navigate")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("LoginView")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
  }
}
```

Your LoginView:

```
struct LoginView: View {
 @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

  var body: some View {

      Button(action: {
         self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
      }) {
          Image(systemName: "gobackward").padding()
      }
      .navigationBarHidden(true)

  }
}
```