# Initialise data from document before views are shown in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a document based swiftui app. The document holds URL values that need to be evaluated before the app is shown. In my production app this consists of a number of activities but the example code below highlights my issue.

Document structure has url's to images that need to be combined to be shown in a view immediately after opening the app. This list of URLs needs to be read and transformed and then displayed. This list of URLs will change based on the URLs the user adds to the array - which then need to be reprocessed. I also have to process video. Any help here appreciated.

My thought was to somehow load the data into a class with an **@Published** version of Doc.images, but I can't figure out how to do this before views are shown.

**Alternative approach for future viewers:** load a temporary screen that does all this processing and once done loads my main view. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967174/swift-ui-navigation-from-splash-screen-to-another-screen-automatically-with-dela](https://An%20alternative%20approach%20would%20be%20to%20load%20a%20temporary%20screen%20that%20does%20all%20this%20processing%20and%20once%20done%20loads%20my%20main%20view.%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967174/swift-ui-navigation-from-splash-screen-to-another-screen-automatically-with-dela)

```
struct Doc: Codable {

    var images: [URL]
    
    init(images: [URL]) {
        self.images = images
    }
}
```

App initialisation looks like this

```
struct TestInitialiseFromDocDocument: FileDocument, Codable {
    var document: Doc

    init() {
        //Test data
        
        let imageA = URL(string: "location a")!
        let imageB = URL(string: "location b")!
        let imagesCollection = [imageA, imageB]
        
        let newDoc = Doc(images: imagesCollection)
        self.document = newDoc
    }

    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.exampleText] }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
              let _ = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
              
        else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        let fileContents = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)

        
        self = fileContents
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        let data =  try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        return .init(regularFileWithContents: data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your idea of using `@Published` is a good one. To use it before the UI appears, 
use the `.onAppear {...}`. See also the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/
Also have a look at this link, it gives you examples of how to manage data in your app using `ObservableObject class` 
with the `@Published`:  
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: Thanks for the information. Hope you're doing ok over there. Stay safe.